# Как развернуть даты в зависимости от количества купленных товаров

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите, как решить следующую задачу:

Высчитываем пациентов на терапии в зависимости от количества купленных препаратов.
Допустим, пациент купил 09.2017 одну упаковку, значит он на терапии 09.2017.
Если он купил 10.2017 три упаковки, значит нужно его "разложить", что он был на терапии 10.2017,11.2017,12.2017.

Как это сделать запросом T-SQL, чтобы с условно одной строки с датой 10.2017 было еще + две строки.
Примерно как ниже

```
  Card      SaleDate amount OnTherapy
12345678    9/1/2017    1   9/1/2017
12345678    10/1/2017   3   10/1/2017
12345678    10/1/2017   3   11/1/2017
12345678    10/1/2017   3   12/1/2017
```

Comment: заведите табличку с датами и джойньте ее, например по date_diff

Answer (score 4):

```
WITH maxi (amount)
AS
( SELECT MAX(amount) amount
  FROM table
),
nums (num)
AS
( SELECT 0 num
  UNION ALL
  SELECT nums.num+1
  FROM nums,maxi
  WHERE nums.num < maxi.amount
)
SELECT Card, SaleDate, amount, DATEADD('d', nums.num, SaleDate) OnTherapy
FROM table, nums
WHERE nums.num < amount
```

Comment: вы быть хоть объяснили что-нибудь, а не просто код. человек может не знает про cte, тем более про рекурсивные

Comment: @teran Я так думаю, что ежели автору чего надо, так спросит...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, внедрил у себя, но выдает ошибку - GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'nums'.

Comment: @ScalandiS Ответ откорректирован в соответствии с ограничениями DBMS.

Comment: Спасибо большое!